# Under windows, WebGL makes use of DirectX Runtime or OpenGL runtime?

Tags: html, opengl, directx, webgl

Under windows, there are two main 3D libraries. I am wondering WebGL use which? is it configurable? Is it configurable per browser?

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome and Firefox will by default make use of [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) wrapper to convert OpenGL API calls to Direct3D 9.0 (to achieve better compatibility with most hardware). Users can change this default behavior but it seems to be very inconvenient to override this (currently it's not possible to change this settings programatically).

All other major browsers (on windows) will use OpenGL.

Comment: Chrome uses ANGLE not for performance but for compatibility. Both DirectX and OpenGL use the same GPU registers and run the same shader assembly instructions, the difference is that not all hardware has OpenGL drivers for >= 2.0 but almost everything has DX9 drivers. It's there just so people don't have to update their drivers to get the right OpenGL support because most companies don't care as much about the OpenGL drivers.

Comment: Webgl use OpenGL by default except for Chrome, is that right?

Comment: I took a look at some Firefox dedicated blogs and it seems Firefox is using ANGLE too, along with Google Chrome. Answer was corrected.

Comment: "all other major browsers (on windows) will use OpenGL" ??? What other major browsers are these? IE doesn't run WebGL.

Comment: @gman "What other major browsers are these???" - Opera Next already supports WebGL and Opera 11 has a special WebGL implementation. Last time I checked (few months ago), Direct3D use in Opera was an obscure topic so I'm counting it as an OpenGL only.

Comment: @marcioAlmada Opera is using DirectX on Windows.

Comment: that's good news, do you know if they are using ANGLE? I've read their entire rendering engine is going hardware accelerated (not only for canvas) and this is the motive for their delays on supporting WebGL.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering WebGL use which?

Depends on the browser and the OS.

> is it configurable?

Depends on the browser.

> Is it configurable per browser?

You mean JavaScript? No.

But why do you care?

Chrome and Firefox use ANGLE so that they work out of the box on a Windows system with only the default drivers supplied by Microsoft installed. For a proper OpenGL implementation installed the user needs to have downloaded and installed the original drivers from the HW vendor. If not, all you get is a rather crappy OpenGL-1.4 implementation/emulation built upon Direct3D 9.

Comment: I care because glLineWidth with ANGLE is broken and it's pissing me off :(