# Why is WebGL Acting as a Wrapper for Direct3D?

Tags: webgl, direct3d, glsles

So today, I got some linker error compiling a shader (I figured it's because I had a function that missed a return statement). But this time, the error message structure was out of ordinary to me:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2ywDKfS.png]

> **D3D** shader compilation failed ...etc

Does this mean that GLSLES code gets converted and compiled as an HLSL shader at runtime? Would this mean that Direct3D is what WebGL turns to in the end? Couldn't WebGL be a wrapper for OpenGL instead and made use of higher GLSL versions and many other features?

Comment: this [other topic on SO] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867040/under-windows-webgl-makes-use-of-directx-runtime-or-opengl-runtime) should point you in the right direction regarding the use of DirectX by WebGL.

Comment: @thoroc Oh, yes! Thank you very much.

Comment: To the general question: Direct3D is better supported "out-of-the-box" by Windows than OpenGL. Modern versions of Windows use Direct3D for all graphics, so the drivers are well-tested and always present. For this reason, WebGL is using Direct3D via [ANGLE](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/angle) which is a wrapper for OpenGL ES. For Universal Windows Platform apps on Windows 10, OpenGL is not supported but you can use ANGLE there as well if apps don't use Direct3D directly.